# how to optimize the performance of Vuetify data table page

Tags: vue.js, meteor, datatable, vuetify.js

[image]

I have attached the image from google chrome's lighthouse performance page. I am using Meteor, Vue, and Vuetify to develop the system and I am new to the technology stack. Backend is really quick to retrieve the result from the DB but the frontend is super slow which you can see in the screenshot. It is taking a lot longer to display the complete page with populated data then it should. I want to optimize it. I am retrieving 1700 records and populating two different Vuetify data tables on the page. but I am displaying only 20 records on the page. records = rows. Please guide me how can I optimize the performance of the app. Thanks in advance.

Edited: 
[image]

Comment: It's hard to say without at least some kind of code snippet. Also, are you running lighthouse on dev or production build? Are you just showing the data from the backend or are you doing some additional (and potentially expensive operation) for each cell in the table?

Comment: I also recommend you to install and use [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) browser extension. Once installed, in your devtools you can go to `Vue` tab and then to `Performance` sub tab. There you can click to `Start` do some actions in browser and stop the recording. Then you can inspect `Component` render and maybe get some additional information on what's slowing your table down.

Comment: @ljubadr I have added the screenshot from the vue-devtools but I have no idea how to utilize this information and how to make any kind of judgement on this.

Comment: You can see that `<VListTile>` is taking a lot of time, so you could look into your logic there and try to optimize it. As I said, without actually seeing any code it's hard to say... Are you using `v-data-table`? You said that you are only showing 20 rows. How are you filtering those 1700 rows on the frontend? Do you have a lot of logic in your templates?

Comment: @ljubadr Yes using v-data-table. Yes showing only 30 rows. Yes, a lot of logic in the template. Initial rendering is really slow but filtering records take less time as compared to the initial rendering. Is there any alternative to the v-data-table. I don't think it would help if I would replace the table with v-for and customer row elements.
I have added the filter code in the description.

Comment: I am opening a dialog on click on the row and In that dialog, I am using the row component and some additional fields. but I don't think it adds up to the initial rendering time.

Comment: Best approach would be to try to simplify one by one column (maybe print raw data). At some point you should see the performance improvement. Than when you know which column is causing the issues, you can try to optimize logic for that column

Comment: @ljubadr would it make a difference if I ditch v-data-table and using some custom table-like structure?

Comment: `v-data-table` should not be that slow... If I were in your place, I would try to find what's making the table render slow. Try to find which column (or columns) are taking long time to render, and maybe try to optimise them a bit. If your columns logic is heavy, then it won't matter if you use `v-for` or `v-data-table`

Comment: You can try to comment out all columns except one and try to see the performance. If it's fast, move to next column

Comment: I've used vuetify in multiple projects so far and I never had issues with slow rendering that wasn't my fault :) If you think there is an issue with the library, maybe you can create an issue on their [github page](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues)

Comment: I have implemented heavyweight/complex plain HTML tables using vuejs and I had no perf. issues. However using v-datatable I am facing terrible rendering time. I think people saying this is not an issue are not really trying to render larger volumes of data. In my case I have a large number of columns. There is an open bug for this issue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9946. Actually this is a typical vuejs issue related to child components being forced to update.